# Scrollview can host only one direct child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I have multiple `LinearLayout`s with a combined height that easily exceeds a device's screen height. So in order to make my layout scrollable, I tried adding in a `ScrollView`, but unfortunately I get the following error:

> Scrollview can host only one direct child

I did some research, but couldn't really make sense of how to solve it, even after reading a couple of solutions. I tried a few changes, but nothing worked for me so far. Any help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="20dip">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 1"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q1_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 2"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q2_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 3"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q3_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 4"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q4_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 5"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q5_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 6"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q6_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 7"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q7_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 8"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q8_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 9"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q9_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 10"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q10_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 11"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q11_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 12"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q12_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 13"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q13_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 14"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q14_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 15"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q15_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 16"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q16_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 17"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q17_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 18"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q18_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 19"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q19_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Question 20"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/q20_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center"/>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Score:"
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/final_score"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0/5"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55175944/6676310

Comment: Scrollview should have only one child (ViewGroup), inside that you can add multiple views.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Wrap all the children inside of another LinearLayout with `wrap_content` for both the width and the height as well as the vertical orientation.

Comment: Does this also work with Constraint Layout nowadays?