# A scroll view can have only one child Android XML file

Tags: java, android, layout, scrollview

So, I want to have a scrollview on my layout. I did this and got `a scroll view can only have one child` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Latitude: "
        android:textSize="15dip" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textSize="15dip" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="Longitute: "
        android:textSize="15dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textSize="15dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="130dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Find Coordinates"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Location Name"
    android:textSize="10dip" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Email"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDesc"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Description"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFlowers"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:hint="Flowers"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPlants"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-35dip"
    android:hint="Plants"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFruit"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:hint="Fruit"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextVeggies"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-35dip"
    android:hint="Veggies"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSun"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="115dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Sunday"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Save Location" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/seeAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dip"
    android:text="See all" />

</ScrollView>
```

Then, following the answer to this question

[java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081217/java-lang-illegalstateexception-scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child)

I did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="95dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Latitude: "
        android:textSize="15dip" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textSize="15dip" >

    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation = "vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:text="Longitute: "
        android:textSize="15dip" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="unknown"
        android:textSize="15dip" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="130dip"
    android:layout_height="30dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Find Coordinates"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextName"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Location Name"
    android:textSize="10dip" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Email"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDesc"
    android:layout_width="264dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Description"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFlowers"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:hint="Flowers"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextPlants"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-35dip"
    android:hint="Plants"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextFruit"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
    android:hint="Fruit"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextVeggies"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="180dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="-35dip"
    android:hint="Veggies"
    android:ems="10"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextSun"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="115dip"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Sunday"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveLocation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="90dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="Save Location" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/seeAll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="120dip"
    android:text="See all" />

</ScrollView>
```

but still no luck. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You're trying to use ScrollView as a layout? Normally, ScrollView is used to allow a user to scroll through its single child view, not to make your whole Activity UI scrollable. Please clarify what it is you're actually trying to accomplish there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The key here is

> ScrollView can host only one **direct** child

"direct" being the keyword. So you can have

```
<ScrollView
    ...>
    <LinearLayout>
       ....
       <!-- you can have as many Views in here as you want -->
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

So, the `LinearLayout` in the above example would be your **one direct child**. And that child can have as many children as you want. Which means you can have all of your other `LinearLayout`s inside that first one. But you can't have more than one on the same hierarchical level.