# If internet is off getting error java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, exception

I am using NestedScrollView with single layout but they give me error like below when Internet is off,  if internet on this is working fine.

```
Process: com.oktested, PID: 8028
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
            at androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView.addView(NestedScrollView.java:444)
            at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar.showView(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:511)
            at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar$1.handleMessage(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:191)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6662)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

XML Code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_black">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/nsvFaces"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_70sdp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
                    android:text="@string/browsebyfaces"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_24sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvFaces"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_70sdp"
                android:alpha="1"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_home" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_vector_arrow" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sideMenu"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_50sdp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_12sdp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_sky" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have also search more result but not getting proper solution and i have already try every solution from below link but not working in my case.

[ScrollView can host only one direct child with relativelayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962348/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child-with-relativelayout)
        [Scrollview can host only one direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699772/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child)
        [A scroll view can have only one child Android XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23820057/a-scroll-view-can-have-only-one-child-android-xml-file)
        [java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081217/java-lang-illegalstateexception-scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child/20081261)

If I am wrong please suggest me and please help me.

Comment: Do you add a layout  programmaticaly to the scrollview ?

Comment: No, I am adding layout only in xml

Answer (score 2):

> `at com.google.android.material.snackbar.BaseTransientBottomBar.showView(BaseTransientBottomBar.java:511)`

Your stack trace tells me that you try to add a Snackbar to the ScrollView.

The Snackbar is tries to find a parent view where it can add its view. You probably called the `Snackbar.make()` function with your ScrollView,  so it tries to add the Snackbar there.
If you pass the RelativeLayout as a parent to the `make` function it will hopefully work.