# Scrollview can host only one direct child although I wrap all in one LinearLayout

Tags: android-linearlayout

Following this link: [Scrollview can host only one direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699772/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child/16699797#16699797),
I do "Wrap all the children inside of another LinearLayout with wrap_content for both the width and the height and vertical orientation."; however I still get that exception. The following is my layout code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appVersionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="@string/appver_text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/libVersionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/libver_text" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sensorSelectButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/sensor_select_button"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/selectSensorTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:text="@string/select_sensor" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bleControlTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/ble_control_title" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bleConnectButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/ble_connect_button"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bleDisconnectButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="@string/ble_disconnect_button"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <!--CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/fileCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/file_check_radiobutton" /-->
</LinearLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataTypeSelectTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/datatype_select_title" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/lefthandCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lefthand_checkbox"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/righthandCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/righthand_checkbox"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/pdCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/posture_data_check_box"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/tdCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/transport_data_check_box"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/onDeskCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="On Desk"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/standCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stand"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/sitCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sit"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/walkCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Walking"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/runCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Running"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/vehicleCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Vehicle"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/busCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bus"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/motoBikeCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Moto Bike"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cyclingCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cycling"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/trainCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Train"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/elevatorCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Elevator"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/stairCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stair"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/accCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Acceleration"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/prWaveCheckBox"
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pressure_wave_data_check_box"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/connectionControlTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="@string/connection_control_title" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bleStartButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="@string/ble_start_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bleStopButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="@string/ble_stop_button" />

    <!--Button
        android:id="@+id/deviceInfoButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:text="@string/get_device_info_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rawDataButton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/raw_mode_button_on"
        android:textSize="12sp" / -->

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dataViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/data_view_title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="372dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pdDataView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/posture_data_view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tdDataView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/transport_data_view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/deviceInfoTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/device_info_view_title" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="174dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/accValueDataView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/acc_value_data_view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/prWaveDataView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/pressure_wave_data_view" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rawDataView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/raw_data_view" />

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
                android:id="@+id/linechart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="280dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/featureDataView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/raw_data_view" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

What is the bug here?

Answer (score 0):

it seems related to ScrollView properties.
The following code works:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```