# cannot put imageview in the scrollview android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to put imageview in the scrollview in android studio, but it doesn't lets me drag and drop imageview in the scrollview.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ccc"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="30dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textColor="#ffffff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homepagetxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

    </LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

I can put it in Linear layout, but it messes up the layout of my screen.
However, I cant put it up in the scroll view like after the linearlayout closing tag.

Is there any limitation of putting imageview in scrollview?

I'd appreciate your kind response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ScrollView can have only one direct child. If you want to put several views in it, you have to put these views in a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout.

[Scrollview can host only one direct child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699772/scrollview-can-host-only-one-direct-child)

Comment: oh.. Is it possible that I can have a linear layout containing another linear layout and a scrollview?

Comment: Yes because a Linear (or Relative) Layout can contain several direct childrens but a scroll view can have only one direct child.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any limitation of putting imageview in scrollview?

No. However, a `ScrollView` can only have one child. At the moment, that is your `LinearLayout`.